# Editable HTML Form with a Save Button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create an HTML application form and send it to applicants through email. each individual has to download the file, fill it out separately and send it back to me.

Is it possible to embed a save button and overwrite the changes permanently ? all I could find was save the changes locally (or as a separate file) which is not what I want. here is a simple form I could find on w3schools:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "overwrite changes permanently"? Your `<input type="button"...` should probably be an `<input type="submit"...`. Then when users click on the button, the contents of the form is submitted to your `/action_page.php` for processing.

Comment: Nice idea, but JS in an email is a big no no ...

Comment: I simply mean "save the changes within the same html file".. I changed it to submit and I got the error: 'Your file was not found'

Comment: You want your form to modify your HTML file? How do you plan on not exposing users’ data to others accessing the same file?

Comment: @esqew I quote: "each individual has to fill it out separately and send it back to me". Did I say others access the SAME file ?!.. each applicant downloads the html file in his/her own computer, fills it out and sends it back to me. is it that complicated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this code](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/how-to-save-form-data-in-a-text-file-using-javascript.htm) instead. all I had to do was change the output to html and style it the way I want. though it saves the changes as a new file but that's ok. I couldn't find anything else :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Save form Data in a Text File using JavaScript</title>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div {
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        input[type=text], textarea, select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        input[type=button]{ 
            width: auto;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 7px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        
        <!--Add few elements to the form-->

        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Enter your name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtAge" placeholder="Enter your age" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <select id="selCountry">
                <option selected value="">-- Choose the country --</option>
                <option value="India">India</option>
                <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Write some message ..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
        </div>

        <!--Add to button to save the data.-->
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="bt" value="Save data to file" onclick="saveFile()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    let saveFile = () => {
        
        // Get the data from each element on the form.
        const name = document.getElementById('txtName');
        const age = document.getElementById('txtAge');
        const email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
        const country = document.getElementById('selCountry');
        const msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        
        // This variable stores all the data.
        let data = 
            '\r Name: ' + name.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Age: ' +age.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Email: ' + email.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Country: ' + country.value + ' \r\n ' + 
            'Message: ' + msg.value;
        
        // Convert the text to BLOB.
        const textToBLOB = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' });
        const sFileName = 'formData.txt';      // The file to save the data.

        let newLink = document.createElement("a");
        newLink.download = sFileName;

        if (window.webkitURL != null) {
            newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
        }
        else {
            newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
            newLink.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(newLink);
        }

        newLink.click(); 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't save the form in Internet Explorer. does anyone know the reason why ?